# Typescript throws error when declearing a variable as this.x = x

Tags: javascript, typescript

I got a `class` and a `constructor` in it. The constructor got a value `x` as a parameter and I want to declare a variable for the class with

```
this.x = x
```

but typescript throws an error:

> TS2339: Property 'x' does not exist in type 'myClass'

Does anyone know how to solve this problem without declaring every single variable extra like "`private x: number;`" --> "`this.x = x`"

Comment: You either have to declare the variable like you mentioned or do `this["x"] = x` (but every time you want to access it you will have to do it like that). Why don't you want to declare it though?

Comment: `this["x"]` will not provide type safety...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you have a constructor parameter, you can just declare an access modifier to make it a field, You don't even need to perform the assignment (typescript will do it for you)

```
class C {
    constructor(public x: number) {} // can also be private or protected instead of public
    m() {
        this.x = 10;
    }
}
new C(1).x // ok, x is declared and is 1
```

Comment: Works perfectly fine but now I got another problem. I am not able to initialize a variable inside of the `constructor` like:

    class C {
        constructor() {
            this.y: number = 10;
        }
    }

Comment: @René those fields have to be declared no way around that. This shorthand only works for constructor parameters that need to be copied to fields. (the `this["y"]` suggestion is a bad idea and will not work anyway under `noImplicitAny`)